# Jenga: When does a player's turn begin?

Tags: jenga

So in a hypothetical jenga game we have two players, let's call them player A and player B. Player A completes a turn, and the tower remains standing for the 10 seconds until player A's turn is over. But before player B touches the tower, it falls over. Does this count as it falling over during Player B's turn? Does player B's turn start 10 seconds after player A places a block, or when player B first touches the tower?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It is not necessarily any player's turn, but Player A would win. Not because player B caused the tower to topple - he didn't. But according to the [rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/jenga.pdf):

> Your turn ends 10 seconds after you stack your block - or as soon as the player to your left touches one.

and

> If you're the last player to stack a block without toppling the tower,
>   you win!"

It doesn't say that the next player's turn begins as soon as those 10 seconds are up, but it doesn't really matter. In this case, player A successfully stacked a block without toppling the tower. It wasn't that player B caused the tower to topple, it's just that player A met the win condition.

Answer (score 1):

From the [rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/jenga.pdf):

> Your turn ends 10 seconds after you stack your block - or as soon as the player to your left touches one.

So in your example the tower has fallen during Player B's turn.